# Adding 2nd fxml within pane of 1st fxml

Tags: java, javafx

I'm brand new to javafx so apologies for the basic question!

My question is how to add a 2nd fxml inside a pane from the 1st fxml.

I've got a mini program here.

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml1.fxml"));
            Parent root = loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

and FXML1 controller

```
    @FXML
    private Button button;

    @FXML
    private Pane pane;

    @FXML
    void load(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Pane fp = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml2.fxml"));
        System.out.println("This should load fxml2");
        pane.getChildren().add(fp);
    }
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }
}
```

I keep getting NPE from the FXML field pane
Hope this makes any sense

cheers

Edit --

Here's the complete stack trace

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml@18/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1857)
    at javafx.fxml@18/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1724)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base@18/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@18/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8797)
    at javafx.controls@18/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
    at javafx.controls@18/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:208)
    at javafx.controls@18/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base@18/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@18/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3881)
    at javafx.graphics@18/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1874)
    at javafx.graphics@18/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2607)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:551)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@18/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at javafx.base@18/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml@18/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:84)
    at javafx.fxml@18/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1852)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.layout.Pane.getChildren()" because "this.pane" is null
    at application.fxml1_controller.load(fxml1_controller.java:26)
    ... 57 more
```

and the fxml's

fxml1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/18" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.fxml1_controller">
   <top>
      <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="This is fxml1" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </top>
   <center>
      <Pane fx:id="pane" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </center>
   <left>
      <Button fx:id="button" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#load" text="load fxml2" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </left>
</BorderPane>
```

fxml2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>


<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/18" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.fxml2_controller">
   <children>
      <Text layoutX="277.0" layoutY="196.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="This is fxml2" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: don't delete and repost a question! instead, edit the previous to make it answerable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72136556/trying-to-add-pane-from-one-controller-to-another-javafx

Comment: repeating: [mcve] required - including the complete stacktrace

Comment: How do you assign a value to pane? You put an @FXML tag, that just says that it should be assigned from the FXML. We need to see that FXML to know how it is being assigned.

Comment: edited with the stacktrace and the fxmls

Comment: It looks good, you *should* be assigning `pane` especially if your button is working. It seems like this could be a compilable example by making the fxml controller 1 into a compilable class.

Comment: I made a simple example with the information you provided and "pane" is not null. You'll need to include more information because what you're describing should work. I had to make the `@FXML` fields public but I think that is particular to my setup.

Comment: That’s it! All I had to o do was make the pane public. Thanks. What in your/our setup requires that it is public?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the module setup. I know javafx changed where you could use the @FXML tag with private members. When I tried, it gave me errors about modules. `Unable to make field private javafx.scene.layout.Pane org.openjfx.FxmlTestController.pane accessible: module org.openjfx does not "opens org.openjfx" to module javafx.fxml` So I made the member public and it worked. I think there is a way to setup the modules to use private fields, but if you dont' need it public can be fine.

Answer (score -4):

Everything in JavaFX is a `Node` (a component which has UI, functionality and is interactable), you should just be able to add one Node to the other.